# The variables of a public object disappear after assigning the address to a local pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, arduino

I have a public object called "Azimuth azimuth(..)".
I want to give this object to an other object called "Scanner scan(azimuth)", this way the scan object can easily use the azimuth object.
The constructor of "scanner" saves the address of the azimuth object to a pointer.
The scan object calls a function like scan.scanRoom().
The azimuth object can be accessed, but the variables assigned to it are invalid (extremely high values).
What is causing this? And how should I solve this?

## the code:

> main:

```
Azimuth azimuth(5,6,2000,7);
ScanAngles scan(sensor,azimuth,elevation);
```

> ScanAngles:

```
class ScanAngles
{
private:
  Sensor* sensor;
  Azimuth *azimuth;
  Elevation *elevation;
public:
  ScanAngles(Sensor sensor , Azimuth azimuth, Elevation elevation)
  {
    this->sensor = &sensor;
    this->azimuth = &azimuth;
    this->elevation = &elevation;
  }
```

> The function:

```
void ScanAngles::getFullScan(int stepWidth, int stepHeight)
{
  Serial.print(this->azimuth->getRotation());
}
```

Some pictures of the debugger:

[The values in the main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFEKH.png)

[The values when called in the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq4wO.png)

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Look into pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the objects into the `ScanAngles` constructor by value, the objects are therefore copied into temporary values, storing pointers to these tempories is undefined behaviour.

You should pass by reference instead:

```
ScanAngles(Sensor& sensor , Azimuth& azimuth, Elevation& elevation)
```

Comment: @idclev i seem to remember that according to the standard storing the pointers beyond the lifetime of the tempories is indeed undefined behaviour, obviously in most cases nothing bad will happen until you dereference the pointers

Comment: @AlanBirtles That is not the case, but using the pointer (even if only to copy it) has implementation-defined behavior, see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic#stc-4.

Comment: Thanks! Any tips on why my post has dislikes, so I can improve it?

Comment: Some people just down vote questions that they think have very simple answers